# kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (401) Reason: Unauthorized; What IAM to create/delete GKE pods

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to read a list of active pods in my GKE cluster.  I also want to be able to programmatically create and/or delete pods using a python client.  What IAM access rights should I grant my service account to accomplish this?  Since I've been trying almost anything to get it working this service account currently has `Kubernetes Engine Admin`, `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin`, and `Kubernetes Engine Developer` access.

Here's some sample code that attempts to read the pods in the 'default' namespace at my cluster's IP

```py
import kubernetes
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


def get_access_config(cluster_ip):
    # access the k8s cluster, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    access_token = credentials.get_access_token()

    # Create a configuration object
    access_configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()

    # Specify the access configuration to access k8s cluster
    access_configuration.host = f"https://{cluster_ip}:443"
    access_configuration.verify_ssl = False
    access_configuration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + access_token.access_token}
    return access_configuration


def get_pod_list(access_configuration):
    v1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(kubernetes.client.ApiClient(access_configuration))
    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    ret = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace='default')


cluster_ip = '0.0.0.0'  # replace with your cluster_ip
access_configuration = get_access_config(cluster_ip)
get_pod_list(access_configuration)
```

Whenever I run the `get_pod_list` function, I get the following Traceback:

> ````sh
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<input>", line 3, in
> <module>   File
> "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/<my_env>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py",
> line 12803, in list_namespaced_pod
>     (data) = self.list_namespaced_pod_with_http_info(namespace, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501   File "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/<my_env>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py",
> line 12905, in list_namespaced_pod_with_http_info
>     collection_formats=collection_formats)   File "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/<my_env>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py",
> line 345, in call_api
>     _preload_content, _request_timeout)   File "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/<my_env>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py",
> line 176, in __call_api
>     _request_timeout=_request_timeout)   File "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/<my_env>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py",
> line 366, in request
>     headers=headers)   File "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/<my_env>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py",
> line 241, in GET
>     query_params=query_params)   File "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/envs/<my_env>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py",
> line 231, in request
>     raise ApiException(http_resp=r) kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (401) Reason: Unauthorized HTTP
> response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id':
> '22bd2789-30d0-4be8-a211-277a39396de7', 'Content-Type':
> 'application/json', 'Date': 'Wed, 22 Jul 2020 22:12:17 GMT',
> 'Content-Length': '129'}) HTTP response body:
> {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401} ```
> ````

If my IAM access rights aren't the issue, what's causing this 401 "Unauthorized" error and how should I fix it?

### EDIT/UPDATE

I was still getting the same error even after following the instructions in the current answer.  These instructions seem to be necessary, but not sufficient to solve the problem.

I thought that my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` path variable might be pointing to the wrong JSON file, but I checked with the code below and it's pointing to the right file:

```
import os
os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
```

After checking that, I tried a simpler version of the code from https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python :

```
from kubernetes import client, config

# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace='default')
```

That version WORKED!?!  So, what's the problem/difference with the `GoogleCredentials` version of getting the `api_client` to be loaded into `kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api`?  Is the `GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()` line somehow looking for and finding the wrong credentials?  If so, how can I point it to the right credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide the steps ❓, so this works for me, my service account has Admin GKE access:

Create service account creds:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create cred.json --iam-account  mytestserviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
created key [xxxxxxxxxx] of type [json] as [cred.json] for [mytestserviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]``
```

Activate service account:

```sh
gcloud auth activate-service-account mytestserviceaccount@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=cred.json
```

You can check with:

```
gcloud auth list
                       Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       mytestserviceaccount@dproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        name@sample.com
```

Then:

```sh
gcloud container clusters get-credentials gke-cluster-name --zone us-central1-a --project project
```

Make sure that you allow your user admin to your service account:

[image: image1]

Also, that account has the Kubernetes Admin role:

[image: image2]

A good way to test:

- `kubectl get pods` should work.

I copied the code above and it works with one of my GKE clusters.

✌️

Comment: I followed the instructions and I was able to get all of the tests you provided to work, but I'm still getting the same error.  I wasn't sure how to allow my user to be admin on an existing service account.  I also don't see the `Admin GKE` access role in IAM; can you be more explicit?

Comment: Sure, added an image.

Comment: Any ideas on the new EDIT/UPDATE to this question?

Comment: How about completely removing the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable. I don't have that anywhere it works for me.